# Не удается сформировать заголовок для api запроса на angular

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, angularjs-controller

Написал Контроллер:

```
app.controller('sportsController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http({
    method: 'GET', url: 'https://api.pinnacle.com/v2/sports', headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic UlQ4NDM1NjM6QmV0RGVzayExNw=='
    }
}).
success(function (data) {
    $scope.sports = data.sports;
});
```

});

однако консоль мне пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross Domain Issue.
Попробуйте так:

```
var url = "https://api.pinnacle.com/v2/sports" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  $http({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",method: 'jsonp',url:url,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```